# Pulling the High from one column between to specific rows

Tags: python, pandas, csv

How would you be able to pull the highest number in the **hi** column between the "12/10/2021 9:30" row and the "12/10/2021 10:00" row?

The output of the panda's data frame:

```
        date         hi       lo      open    close     volume
12/10/2021 9:10    175.4   175.31   175.39   175.32     1889
12/10/2021 9:11   175.48   175.34   175.34   175.48     3449
12/10/2021 9:12   175.47   175.42   175.47   175.42      890
12/10/2021 9:13   175.46    175.4   175.43   175.44     5815
12/10/2021 9:14   175.48   175.42   175.42   175.48     7983
12/10/2021 9:15    175.5   175.44   175.48   175.44     5813
12/10/2021 9:16   175.44   175.35   175.44   175.38     9524
12/10/2021 9:17   175.38   175.25   175.35   175.38     8514
12/10/2021 9:18   175.48   175.38   175.41   175.48     4313
12/10/2021 9:19   175.45   175.39   175.45   175.41    14117
12/10/2021 9:20   175.43   175.36   175.36   175.36     8298
12/10/2021 9:21   175.39   175.32   175.37   175.39     2768
12/10/2021 9:22    175.4   175.34   175.39   175.38     4721
12/10/2021 9:23   175.41   175.37   175.39   175.37     3563
12/10/2021 9:24   175.49   175.41   175.42   175.49     1989
12/10/2021 9:25   175.48   175.25   175.41   175.26    15013
12/10/2021 9:26    175.3   175.15   175.26   175.18     7241
12/10/2021 9:27   175.26    175.1   175.16   175.16    23590
12/10/2021 9:28   175.19    175.1   175.12   175.15    10780
12/10/2021 9:29   175.27   175.15   175.15   175.23    12863
12/10/2021 9:30   176.03   175.14   175.25   175.71  1370478
12/10/2021 9:31    175.9   175.46   175.71    175.9   435577
12/10/2021 9:32    176.1   175.68   175.88   175.73   485381
12/10/2021 9:33   175.87   175.37   175.74  175.615   450575
12/10/2021 9:34    176.1   175.52  175.609   176.05   485467
12/10/2021 9:35   176.11   175.54   176.06   175.64   484336
12/10/2021 9:36   176.15   175.51   175.65  176.005   462430
12/10/2021 9:37   176.32   175.87  175.992   176.17   502685
12/10/2021 9:38   176.53   176.14  176.165   176.47   668669
12/10/2021 9:39  176.556  176.345   176.48  176.367   577773
12/10/2021 9:40   176.42  176.005   176.35  176.005   388618
12/10/2021 9:41   176.05   175.66   176.01   176.01   511461
12/10/2021 9:42   176.03   175.81  176.011   175.89   277475
12/10/2021 9:43  176.215   175.88  175.908  176.188   315341
12/10/2021 9:44   176.45   176.01   176.18  176.025   426582
12/10/2021 9:45   176.36   175.88   176.02  175.935   513756
12/10/2021 9:46   176.03   175.76   175.94    175.8   367906
12/10/2021 9:47  175.775   175.45  175.775   175.56   481068
12/10/2021 9:48   175.76   175.45   175.55  175.739   369607
12/10/2021 9:49   175.89   175.56   175.73   175.66   290529
12/10/2021 9:50   175.86   175.55   175.66   175.83   310516
12/10/2021 9:51   176.12   175.81   175.84   176.01   428011
12/10/2021 9:52   176.06  175.721  176.015   175.83   275272
12/10/2021 9:53   176.01  175.745   175.83   175.78   291982
12/10/2021 9:54  175.895   175.67   175.79  175.695   188332
12/10/2021 9:55  175.705   175.24  175.685  175.375   448620
12/10/2021 9:56   175.38   175.05   175.38  175.155   430128
12/10/2021 9:57    175.4  174.925   175.15  174.925   453117
12/10/2021 9:58  175.001   174.69   174.92  174.775   422128
12/10/2021 9:59   175.21   174.75  174.775   175.18   380997
12/10/2021 10:00   175.51   175.09   175.18   175.45   361698
12/10/2021 10:01   175.63   175.36  175.455   175.42   260332
12/10/2021 10:02   175.49   175.21   175.43   175.36   231188
12/10/2021 10:03   175.54   175.33   175.34  175.533   209592
12/10/2021 10:04   175.57   175.25   175.53    175.4   210473
12/10/2021 10:05  175.588   175.27    175.4   175.51   239867
```

My desired output >> *"Highest Price between 9:30 - 10:00 is 176.556"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a slicing operation with multiple conditions. Kindly try:

```
df = df[(df['date'] >= "12/10/2021 9:30") & (df['date'] <= "12/10/2021 10:00")]['hi'].max()
```

However you might need to transform the date column to datetime format to properly filter it. This can be done with:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Comment: Works perfectly thankyou! @CeliusStingher

Comment: Glad to be of help! Feel free to accept the answer to mark your question as answered and reward us with some score! :)